# Extrinsic curvature calculation

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature, conformal-field-theory

In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.13943) paper section 3.2 the author uses the second junction condition to derive equation 3.8
$$
K_{1ab} = \frac{1}{L_1}\tanh\left(\frac{\rho_1^*}{L_1}\right)h_{ab}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;K_{2ab} = -\frac{1}{L_2}\tanh\left(\frac{\rho_2^*}{L_2}\right)h_{ab}
$$
the $K_{iab}$ are the extrinsic curvature tensors of the $i$th CFT.

Given the metric
$$
ds^2= \frac{L}{y}\cosh^2\left(\frac{\rho}{L}\right)(-dt^2+dy^2)
$$
How can I calculate the extrinsic curvature tensor $K_{ab}$? This should be fairly straightforward since the induced metric only has 2 dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The starting point should be eq.(3.4), let us denote it by $g_{ab}$;
2. The metric you wrote down is $h_{ab}$;
3. The normal vector is $n^a = \{1,0,0\}$;
4. The extrinsic curvature will be calculated by $K_{ab}=\frac{1}{2}n_i g^{ij}\partial_j g_{ab}$ (from the Lie derivative of metric along the normal vector), and the $\rho$-$\rho$ component must be zero.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you explain the formulae you have used for the extrinsic curvature and why it is the Lie derivative of metric along the normal vector? Also, why is the normal vector $n^a = (1,0,0)$?

Comment: That is the definition of extrinsic curvature, see e.g. eq.(4.46) in Claus Kiefer's book "quantum gravity" 3rd ed.

Comment: Thank you, can you also explain the form of $n^a$?

Comment: The induced metric $h_{ab}$ and the normal vector is chosen by authors. Since there is not $\rho$-$\rho$ component in $h_{ab}$, it is natural to take the normal vector $\{1, 0, 0\}$ which is orthogonal to $h_{ab}$.

Comment: Thank you again. One last thing I want to ask is how you get $K_{ab}=\frac{1}{2}n_i g^{ij}\partial_j g_{ab}$ from the Lie derivative. Can you include a small derivation from $K_{ab}=\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{L}_n g_{ab}$ to the form you have?